# Write BitSet of 8 bits to file (C++)

Tags: c++, byte, bitset

I have a BitSet of 8 bits.

How would I convert those 8 bits to a byte then write to file?

I have looked everywhere and only find converting the other way.

Thanks alot!

Comment: What's a `BitSet`? Where is it defined?

Comment: Convert your `BitSet` to a `FlooBlar` and call the `jifiddle()` member function on your `FileGizmo` object.

Comment: are you referring to this? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are talking about C++ STL bitsets, the answer is to convert the bitset to int (ulong to be precise), and casting the result into a char.

Example:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
   bitset<8> x;
   char byte;

   cout << "Enter a 8-bit bitset in binary: " << flush;
   cin >> x;
   cout << "x =       " << x << endl;
   byte = (char) x.to_ulong();
   cout << "As byte:  " << (int) byte << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/

> They can also be directly inserted and extracted from streams in binary format.

You don't need to convert anything, you just write them to the output stream.

Aside from that, if you really wanted to extract them into something you're used to,  `to_ulong` and `to_string` methods are provided.

If you have more bits in the set than an unsigned long can hold and don't want to write them out directly to the stream, then you're either going to have convert to a string and go that route, or access each bit using the `[]` operator and shift them into bytes that you're writing out.

Comment: If I "just write them to the output stream" as you say, the output stream contains a series of '0' and '1' characters. When the docs say "inserted and extracted from streams in binary format" I would have expected groups of 8 bits to be written out as bytes. eg.[code] bitset<8> F("01000110"); ofstream fs("test.txt"); fs << F;[/code] would result in test.txt containing the letter 'F', not the string "01000110".

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fstream std::ofstream`:

```
#include <fstream>
std::ofstream os("myfile.txt", std::ofstream::binary);
os << static_cast<uint_fast8_t>(bitset<8>("01101001").to_ulong());
os.close();
```